# Export labels from autocad to qgis

Tags: qgis, labeling, import, autocad

Is there a way to export my labels from AutoCAD into QGIS?

Right now i have to label everything again in QGIS. importing an dxf-file does not work. Only points, lines or polygons will be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select on Autocad the layer you want to export by turning off the others. Then save the file on AutoCAD in .dxf.

On QGIS insert the .dxf as a vector file and select only what you need. In my case for example I wanted to export text files that contain coordinates:

[image]

Now the points contain in the attributes table the coordinates that I want to transform into labels:

[image]

All you have to do is go to Properties>Labels and select the values you want to set.

[image]